# Is it possible to construct a function to make a poor man's Mathematica database?

Tags: programming, data-structures, data-format, excel, data-acquisition

I have a function that is set up to write to a database with 10-20 standard variables with 10 fields each, but the application is going to a place where database access is not available.  Can Mathematica read an Excel file and pick up the portions of the file that relate to one of these 20 variables, change them if needed and write the whole thing back again?  If so, how would that be accomplished?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  See http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ImportingAndExporting.html  You could keep each "table" in a separate Excel file or de-normalize the entire database and store it in a single file.  You could also just store everything in CSV.

Comment: Beware of where you are going ... Excel is not transactional, not multiuser, not robust, ... it is NOT a DB

Comment: @belisarius Totally agree.  I was trying for a read it all in and write it all out type of solution.  No transactions available.

Comment: @Jagra that is certainly an easy solution, but to be able to do this as one file would be best.  On the read I get the whole file, but if a new variable must be written, the previous variables must be held as well. This is the sticking point for me.  How to make sure the whole file maintains it's structure when adding another variable.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not mySQL or one of the other free databases + DatabaseLink (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/DatabaseLink/tutorial/Overview.html).  This would enable you to manipulate a real database directly from Mathematica.  Also, reasonably portable.  You could even access one of those online databases

Comment: @Jagra this program would normally access a db using DatabaseLink.  In this case a connectivity to that database is not possible. Thanks!

Comment: There is a way to manipulate Excel like you would with VBA: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4594/open-excel-file-with-mathematica

Comment: It's probably much better to go with a real database. Having said that, perhaps you could use [Leonid's SQL DSL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4788373/952600) as a starting point and just operate on mathematica lists, which you could export to a file.

Comment: @Ajasja this looks very promising!  Thank you!

Comment: @FaysalAberkane  Interesting approach!  I know nothing about Com objects!  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the comments you have several options:

- Use `Import` and `Export` to work with Excel files (noted: this is not straightforward with problems mentioned in the comments).
- Use [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/DatabaseLink/tutorial/Overview.html) answer to manipulate the Excel file like it is done in VB.
- Using [Leonid's SQL DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4788373/952600) as a way to get database like syntax while keeping all the data in *Mathematica* lists.

I would also like to add that *Mathematica* comes with a built in, standalone, database called HSQL. Wherever *Mathematica* exists that database also exists and I wonder if perhaps you missed this when you said that you cannot use databases where this code is going. There is an example of how to set up an HSQL database as well as many example queries [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1188/731).

Comment: I was not aware of this!  Thanks very much for your answer!