# Assign the contents of a "Copy" operation programmatically to a variable?

Tags: import, data

While an earlier question [Cut and paste data from a spreadsheet](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8997/cut-and-paste-data-from-a-spreadsheet)  nominally addresses the issue, a year has past since its OP asked it and I hope that others have come across simpler or more direct ways to do this.  I think a new solution might interest the community.

I often want to get values (numbers, dates, ...) from a spreadsheet someone has sent me into Mathematica.

`Import[...]` works fine, but seems a bit cumbersome, when I just want to grab something like a single column or row of values and work with them immediately.

"Copy/Paste" can give one odd results.  Set up a short list of numbers in a spreadsheet ...

[image]

and copy them into Mathematica:

[image]

This seems a bit inconsistent and neither of these gives one a list of the data elements like `Import[...]`.

Note: I use Mac OS X if it makes any difference.

---

Mr. Wizard supplies a pretty good solution in the original question, which references code for a palette that Szabolcs posted at [see page](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/pasting-tabular-data-from-the-web.html), see *Pasting tabular data into notebooks*.

I've added a title and minor formatting to the palette:

```
CreatePalette[
 Column[{Button["TSV", 
    Module[{data, strip}, 
     data = NotebookGet[ClipboardNotebook[]][[1, 1, 1]];
     strip[s_String] := 
      StringReplace[s, RegularExpression["^\\s*(.*?)\\s*$"] -> "$1"];
     strip[e_] := e;
     If[Head[data] === String, 
      NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], 
       ToBoxes@Map[strip, ImportString[data, "TSV"], {2}]]]], 
    ImageSize -> 85], 
   Button["CSV", 
    Module[{data, strip}, 
     data = NotebookGet[ClipboardNotebook[]][[1, 1, 1]];
     strip[s_String] := 
      StringReplace[s, RegularExpression["^\\s*(.*?)\\s*$"] -> "$1"];
     strip[e_] := e;
     If[Head[data] === String, 
      NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], 
       ToBoxes@Map[strip, ImportString[data, "CSV"], {2}]]]], 
    ImageSize -> 85], 
   Button["Table", 
    Module[{data}, 
     data = NotebookGet[ClipboardNotebook[]][[1, 1, 1]];
     If[Head[data] === String, 
      NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], 
       ToBoxes@ImportString[data, "Table"]]]], ImageSize -> 85]}, 
  Alignment -> {Center, Center}], WindowTitle -> "Paste Data", 
 WindowSize -> {85, Fit}]
```

One can install this by choosing **Palettes > Install Palette** (from the file menu) then provide the source file, palette name, and installation directory to the Install Mathematica Item dialog, and click **Finish**.

---

This works, but it does not have the immediacy that one gets used to when working with Mathematica, so...

Does a simple way exist to assign the contents of a "Copy" operation (from a spread sheet or csv file) programmatically to a variable as a list of elements, which one could immediately press into service?

Given that a clipboard appears to hold copies of content in different formats, an elegant solution might involve a right click to select how one wanted it pasted.  Maybe a feature request to Wolfram would do it (eventually:-).

Comment: Oops; it's a duplicate.  Well, I think it is.  Please review the marked question, especially my answer there, and let me know if you feel it is not.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - Duplicate? Kind of, but the answers, excepting yours, don't provide solutions for what I'd like to see.  While yours does (I just implemented it;-), having done so makes me think we can make it better by: naming the palette & supplying steps to install it using `Palette -> Install palette...?`. Also, even your answer has intermediate steps. A year since the original, might not others have come across simpler or more direct ways to do this?  I think a new solution might interest the community, but maybe we could spark new contributions to the original.  Thoughts?

Comment: If you edit the question to: (1)reference the earlier one, (2)state that you are using Szabolcs's palette and explain how it basically works, and (3)describe how you would like to improve upon it if possible, I will happily reopen it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Windows users something could perhaps be created using NETLink. For a basic demonstration:

```
Needs["NETLink`"];
InstallNET[];
LoadNETType["System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard"];
```

Now copy the data in Excel and evaluate:

```
ImportString[Clipboard`GetText[], "Table"]
(* {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}} *)
```

Comment: While I can't use this solution on OS X, +1 for helping that other part of the universe.