# How to copy and paste $n$ lines from a text editor to $n$ cells?

Tags: import, cells

If I copy from an external editor to Mathematica notebook a block of lines (with a code)

```
line 1
line 2
...
line n
```

then whole text is copied to a single cell.
I can now use `n-1` times "Divide cell" and manually create `n` new cells for each line. If `n` is big, then this is a hard work.
Exists some better method how do it ? For example before copying insert some special characters into text (representing an end of cell) ?

Comment: What cell style do you want the resulting cells to have?

Comment: I need a InputForm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do it this way. I would write a function

```
pasteLines[txt_, styl_] := (CellPrint @ Cell[#, styl] & /@ StringSplit[txt, "\n"];)
```

To use it, I would first write

```
pasteLines["", "Input"]
```

I would line copy the text I wanted from the external editor onto the clipboard and paste it between the quotes in the empty string (1st argument), getting

```
pasteLines["line 1
line 2
 ...
line n", "Input"]
```

Evaluating this last expression, gives

[image]

These are all normal input cells that can be edited and evaluated.

This can be made more user friendly. You could merge this MikeLimaOscar's answer, eliminating the `txt` argument, and getting the text from the clip board programatically. You could incorporate the function into paste button which you put on a palette, available for frequent use. (I'm sorry to say I don't have the time to develop this second idea.)

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Comment: For my purposes (always want an input cell, want to be able to delete all output, fix issues with output being placed at the bottom of a group of cells rather than underneath the cell), I use this variant:

`pasteLines[txt_] := (CellPrint[Cell[#, "Input" , CellAutoOverwrite -> False,  GeneratedCell -> False]] & /@ Reverse@StringSplit[txt, "\n"];)`

Answer (score 13):

It is not straightforward to access the clipboard contents but one way, that doesn't involve writing and reading from temporary notebooks is to use the undocumented [`ClipboardNotebook`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/805/what-are-some-useful-undocumented-mathematica-functions/807#807) function:

```
CellPrint /@ StringSplit[NotebookGet[ClipboardNotebook[]][[1, 1, 1]], "\n"];
```

See also this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58623/5414) which mentions some caveats.  This prints strings as text cells.  See the documentation for [`CellPrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellPrint.html) if you require another form.