# Why can't I paste data from Notepad into Mathematica 10 in Windows 8.1?

Tags: version-10

I can't paste data that I have copied from Notepad in Windows 8.1 into Mathematica 10. I was able to do this when I had Windows 7 and Mathematica 8.

Now when I try to paste into Mathematica 10 using Ctrl-V or the Edit->Paste Menu, I get an error "bing" sound.

Comment: At the very least we need to know what kind of data you are pasting.  An actual example, if small enough, would be even better.

Comment: An example of data I tried to paste is
81,35,46,43,40,69,50,45,60,32,60,62,72,59,52

Comment: I have no problem pasting that from Notepad in Windows 7 x64 into Mathematica 10.1.0.  I wonder if Notepad in Windows 8.1 is copying in something other than plain ASCII text?  Does it matter what kind of Cell you paste into?  Can you still use [this palette](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9010/121) or does that give errors too?  (Not that it solves everything but just as a datapoint.)

Comment: That works! Thank you!

Comment: To clarify, yes, the link to cut and paste data from a spreadsheet worked. I wasn't interested in Notepad per se, I just wanted to paste my data and pasting in from a spreadsheet works fine for me.

Comment: Very strange problem.  At least you seem to have a work-around for now.  I see that this question has been closed, and since it has not yet been reproduced I think that is reasonable.  Nevertheless I hope we eventually understand this better.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I am having a similar issue right now, in Linux Mint 18.3 with Mathematica 11.2. I copied some text within Mathematica and pasted it fine. Next I copied text from somewhere else (say Sublime Text), and tried to paste it into Mathematica, but it simply keeps pasting the previous thing. I wonder if someone ever figured out what was happening?

Comment: Closing and re-opening Mathematica "fixes" the issue