# How do I copy a mathematica column to paste in excel?

Tags: list-manipulation, column

I have a list of elements that I transform into a column:

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

Column[a]  

1
2
3
4
5
```

How do I print this column so it can be copy-pasted in Excel? Any alternative way to accomplish this?

Comment: An alternative to cut-and-paste it to export as an xls file. `Export["a.xls", a]`.  All explained in [How to Export a Spreadsheet](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ExportASpreadsheet.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the column, Copy As -> Plain Text. Paste into Excel.

You can also use `TableForm[a]` as well as `Column[a]`.

For copy & paste from Excel to Mathematica see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9008/363).