# How to paste text with special characters into Mathematica Online

Tags: text, mathematica-online

When using the desktop version of Mathematica, I can copy text from other applications (specifically, a block of data in a spreadsheet) and paste into Mathematica between `"  "` and be asked if I want to escape special characters. This is a fast way of importing from Excel, as explained in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8997/cut-and-paste-data-from-a-spreadsheet).

That doesn't seem to work on Mathematica Online - escape characters aren't added. (In the case of importing data from a spreadsheet following the link above, the input of `ImportString["","TSV"]`  adds multiplication symbols `x` between numbers, giving the *appearance* they will all be multiplied. However, when that cell is evaluated, the data is imported as a list of 1 list. This can easily be partitioned into a matrix, but the point is skip that extra step.)

Is there a way to get Mathematica Online to add escape characters?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to paste it in anyway and fix it up later. For
example. Define a function that takes the input string and
then turns it into a matrix.

```
toMatrix[str_, cols_] := Partition[Interpreter[
   DelimitedSequence[Number]][StringReplace[str,
   "\t" -> ","]], cols];
```

Now, in your browser you type this into a cell

```
toMatrix[" ",2]
```

and paste into the `" "` and where you replace 2
with the number of columns. This may seem similar
to what you already use, but maybe someone else
has a better answer.