# Prevent ImportString from rounding values

Tags: import

I'm trying to import a table from Excel following [this question and answers.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8997/cut-and-paste-data-from-a-spreadsheet) In doing so, strings are kept as strings though numeric values get interpreted as `Real` and some are subsequently rounded. I don't want this rounding to occur.

I think I've identified the fundamental behavior I'm having issues with. One can type (without copy/paste from a spreadsheet) this minimal example:

`ImportString["10000.11", "TSV"]`,

which returns

`{{10000.1}}`.

This pattern repeats throughout the imported table, seemingly when the value is above 10,000.

Is there a simple way to cut/paste from a spreadsheet and not have Mathematica round values? I've created my own methods, but they feel like hacks. (Such as: import the entire table as `String`, then do `StringSplit`, `Flatten`, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually illusory! Mathematica does not round values on import; it just *shows* you a rounded value in the output cell.

To see this, look at

```
ImportString["10000.11", "TSV"] // FullForm
```

If you want to change this display behavior, you can go to Mathematica > Preferences (command + `,` if you're on a Mac), select the Appearance tab, and change the number shown under **Displayed Precision** (which is by default 6).

Comment: I'll mark this as correct, as it demonstrates that MMA knows all the digits are there. But applying `ToString` on the values in a table (or, to the value in the MWE above) returns a string with the unwanted rounded behavior. For my purposes, I am using MMA to format data from a spreadsheet for use in a LaTeX matrix; to use `ToString`, I find I can use `ToString[InputForm[_value_]]` and I get all digits, unrounded.

Comment: Nice. By the way, since another way of doing this is `ToString[value, FormatType -> InputForm]`, If you want, you can make that the default behavior for `ToString`: just evaluate `SetOptions[ToString, FormatType -> InputForm]`. Then (as long as you're in the same kernel session/notebook), `ToString` will not round automatically. (`StandardForm` also seems to work.)