# Exporting data to a new excel sheet of a pre-existing excel file

Tags: export, excel

```
m = Table[i - j, {i, 5}, {j, 6}]
n = Table[i - j, {i, 3}, {j, 7}]
o = Table[i^j, {i, 3}, {j, 7}]
Export["mfile2.xls", {"m Data" -> Transpose[m],"n Data" -> Transpose[n]}]
```

The above code creates a spreadsheet with two sheets named "m-data" and "n-data". Now I would like to be able to add more data to the existing spreadsheet. But when I do this:

```
Export["mfile2.xls", {"o Data" -> Transpose[o]}]
```

The earlier data is deleted and now my `mfile2.xls` just has the one sheet names "o-data" containing o-data.

Is it possible for me to `Export` data into some particular existing sheet and maybe even a specific cell of some pre-existing excel file and/or maybe get MMA to create a new sheet in addition to the existing ones.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4594/open-excel-file-with-mathematica has a hint how to do this if you use .NET.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I spent a bit of time trying to mimic the .NET but I couldn't get it to work. Thanks for linking to it. I'm not very far from getting it. Whatever I am doing, does open the right excel file but as of now closes it right back. I'll look at it again in a few months when I have more time. Right now I have just switched to saving data as "*.dat" Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this approach is not sophisticated enough, but it may come handy if you want to add only a few new sheets to your table or you want to update it regularly.
Given you have created your data "m, n" and have exported it to "mfile2.xls".

You import the data of your XLS-file

```
data = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "mfile2.xls"];
```

and import the names of your sheets

```
sheets = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "mfile2.xls", "Sheets"]
```

Now you create your new data "o".

```
o = Table[i^j, {i, 3}, {j, 7}]
```

Then you rebuild the structure that you have exported earlier

```
olddata = sheets[[#]] -> data[[#]] & /@ Range[Length[sheets]]
```

and you add the data of your new sheet to it

```
newdata = Append[olddata, "o Data" -> Transpose[o]]
```

Finally you export the updated data to the original file

```
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "mfile2.xls", newdata]
```

which gives you an XLS containing all previous sheets along with the new one.

For convenience you can build yourself a function to which you only pass the filename of the XLS you want to append a new sheet to and the new data.

Answer (score 3):

Hope it's not too late...
Suppose you want to dump new data (called here "datanew" and generated somehow) into a new sheet of an existing Excel file named "oldfile.xlsx" containing (in sheet 1) data ("dataold"). 
What I do is:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
dataold=Import["oldfile.xlsx"]
Export["oldfile.xlsx",{dataold,datanew}]
```

What you are doing is importing the data already existing and then dumping it back again in sheet 1 but, you also dump "datanew" in sheet 2.
You can name each new sheet:

```
Export["oldfile.xlsx",{"Old Data"->dataold,"New Data"->datanew}]
```

(The new sheets have names: Old Data, New Data)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function which does the job for me. Just make sure that your file is in the same notebook directory.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
ExportExcel[FileName_, NewData_] := Module[{OldData},
 If[FileExistsQ[FileName] == True,
    OldData = Import[FileName];
    Export[FileName, AppendTo[OldData, NewData]],
    Export[FileName, NewData]
   ]
  ]
```