# Import Excel data forcing links (ie workbooks) to be updated

Tags: import, spreadsheets

We have noticed importing data from an Excel spreadsheet doesn’t update links.

The problem with this is if you import a spreadsheet that comprises of linked workbooks data and those workbooks have been updated then stale data ie **NOT** the latest) is retrieved.

[image]

Opening workbooks using the Excel Object Model does support a parameter to UpdateLinks.

[image]

Is there an undocumented way to force Mathematica to open spreadsheets and update the links?

```
Import["c:\\temp\\Exercises.xlsx",{"Sheets","Sheet1"}][[1;;18;;1, 1;;16;;1]];
```

Comment: You can open the spreadsheet using the object model from within Mathematica e.g. [Open Excel file with Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4595/363) - you will have to add the update command.  Please post your solution here for future reference.

Comment: Another option is to create a VBA script that update your xlsx file, and than you can import it. you can use `Run` command to run the script.