# How to access an already opened Excel file in Mathematica?

Tags: excel

This post [4594](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4594) shows how to open a existent Excel file with Mathematica. And this [6686886](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686886) shows how to do what I need, but in C#. This [12282310](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282310) is another related one.

How can I connect to a spreadsheet that is already open?

Answer (score 12):

Using SE as my [rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) to organize ideas worked just nice. I found the answer in [NETLinkUserGuide](https://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/NETLinkUserGuide/NETLinkUserGuide.pdf).

To get current Excel session use `GetActiveCOMObject` instead of `CreateCOMObject`. Here is a code example.

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
InstallNET[]
excel=GetActiveCOMObject["Excel.Application"]
workbook=excel@Workbooks["MySpreadsheet.xlsx"];
worksheet=workbook@Worksheets["Sheet1"];
worksheet@Range["A1"]@Value="1, 2, 3 testing"
```

To get your active workbook use:

```
With[{$name=excel@ActiveWorkbook@Name},
    workbook=excel@Workbooks[$name]
]
```

instead of:

```
workbook=excel@Workbooks["MySpreadsheet.xlsx"];
```

PS: any tip to replace code injection using `With` is welcome.

Comment: Humanity needs more Ducks (plus 1 Quacker).

Comment: +1 Seems promising! Its a pity that all this isn't more explored by WR. After their ?acquisition? of the "link for excel", I was hoping for its inclusion in standard Mathematica... and, who knows, allowing for Enterprise CDF to work as an Excel computational kernel on previously signed user functions. With the Enterprise, I always have the feeling that I'm paying too much for too little...