# Using Wolfram Library Reference in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, interoperability

Long time ago I did [this question](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2014/May/msg00074.html) to MathGroup, but without success.

In Excel VBA, in Tool/References, there is a option called **"Wolfram Mathematica Control 8.0 Type Library"**

I belive that [Mathematica link for Excel](http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/excel_link/) uses that.
Someone knows how to use it? Any code examples?

[image]

Comment: @p-fonseca have you used that?

Comment: No! But I'm extremely interested in the subject :-)

Comment: @P.Fonseca I was wondering if I could link Excel and WL using Enterprise CDF with this component.. would be very interesting.

Comment: @P.Fonseca I think this  [80186](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80186)  interests you.

Answer (score 5):

The *Wolfram Mathematica Control* is the COM footprint of the CDF Player Internet Explorer plug-in.  Here is the information page for the plug-in from the Internet Explorer Add-on Manager:

[image: Internet Explorer plug-in information screenshot]

The registry entries for the DLL are as is typical for Internet Explorer plug-ins, especially the *EnableFullPage* and *Implemented Categories* keys.

[image: REGEDIT screenshot]

The type library exposes few members, largely useful only when the player is embedded within Internet Explorer:

[image: type library screenshot]

Alas, this COM object would seem to offer little of value within the context of Excel.

Comment: "Alas ... little of value within the context of Excel."  :-(  What a pity

Comment: @WReach Tks +1. Interesting... I added the reference and tested a small Sub:
Sub testMathControl();
    Set mc = New MathControl;
End Sub
And wolfram kernel as lunched in Task Manager. But no idea on how to communicate to it.